# How to erase multiple elements from std::vector<> by index using erase function?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector `a` storing values `[0 1 2 3 5]` and other vector `removelist` storing the indexes to be removed `[0 1 2]` in order to leave `[3 5]` at the end. When I'm implementing the following code, it would remove items unexpectedly since the vector `a` will be changing order during the process. Is there any way for me to achieve my target?

```
 for (int i = 0; i<removelist.size() ; i++)     
    a.erase(a.begin() + removelist[i]);
```

Comment: Is the `removelist` ordered?

Comment: @tkausl Even more, everything seems to be ordered. I'd ask if this is the case. Is each array actually ordered?

Comment: The removelist is not ordered , but it can be sorted if needed.

Comment: @skypjack it doesn't matter if the `a` vector is ordered as he removes it by  indices not by values. But his example is buggy (there is no index 5 in a vector with size 5)

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand my question. The removelist is a reference list for removing a[0], a[1] and a[2].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reverse the order you remove values, i.e. use the reverse iterators of `removelist`. This of course relies on `removelist` being sorted.

Perhaps something like

```
std::sort(removelist.begin(), removelist.end());  // Make sure the container is sorted
for (auto &i = removelist.rbegin(); i != removelist.rend(); ++ i)
{
    a.erase(a.begin() + *i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily more efficient, but you can do this without sorting using `remove_if`:

```
auto& rm = removelist; // for brevity

a.erase(remove_if(begin(a), end(a), [&](int i) {
  auto idx = distance(begin(v), find(begin(v), end(v), i));
  return find(begin(rm), end(rm), idx) != end(rm);
}, end(a));
```

Comment: NOTE: Using `find(begin(v), end(v), i)` will lead to unexpected result when there are the elements in the vector `v` are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to copy the elements you want to keep to a new vector:

```
// pseudocode:
vector tmp;
tmp.reserve(a.size() - removelist.size());
for (i=0; i<a.size(); ++i) {
    if (i not in removelist) {
        tmp.push_back(a[i]);
    }
}
a.swap(tmp);
```

Notes:

- You have to make sure that the indices are unique, otherwise the preallocation fails.
- This avoids various reallocations using the preallocated, temporary vector. The reallocations of `a` also avoid the index shift in your approach.
- If the elements in `removelst` are sorted, this can be implemented a bit more efficiently.
- I wonder where that list comes from. Can't you remove the elements on the fly instead of creating a temporary list?

Comment: The temporary list is generated by some comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from @Yam Marcovic's answer, not using `find` but use the exact address to find the index:

```
a.erase(std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [&](const int& i) {
  auto idx = ((void*)&i - (void*)&*a.begin());
  return std::find(removelist.begin(), removelist.end(), idx) != removelist.end();
}), a.end());
```